# Force an async function to wait for my module to load its porperties

Tags: discord, discord.js

For my discord bot, I want to have my bot check if it has cached the server's prefix before querying mongo for the prefix. The issue is that the asynchronous function does not wait for the cache to be initialized before trying to read it.

```
const common = require('../util/common');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const math = require('mathjs');
const guildSettings = require('../schema/guildSchema');

module.exports = {
    name: "test2",
    description: "a test command!",
    usage: `\`${process.env.PREFIX}test2\``,
    category: "Admin",
    alias: ["test2"],
    disabled: false,
    cache: {},
    async execute(message, args){ 
        
        let prefix = await getPrefix();
        console.log(this.cache);
        message.reply(` your prefix is ${prefix}`);

        async function getPrefix(){
            if (!this.cache[message.guild.id]){
                let settings = await guildSettings.findOne({ _id: message.guild.id });
                if (!settings){
                    settings = await guildSettings.create({
                        _id: message.guild.id,
                        prefix: '-',
                    });
                    await settings.save();
                    console.log('entry created')
                }
                this.cache[message.guild.id] = settings.prefix;
                console.log('prefix cached');
                return prefix = this.cache[message.guild.id];
            } else {
                return prefix = this.cache[message.guild.id];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ignore the `console.log()` statements, thats just me trying unsuccessfully to debug a little bit. When I call this command, I get an error because `this.cache` is undefined. How can I make my function wait for the parent properties to be intialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block

```
async function getPrefix(){
            if (!this.cache[message.guild.id]){ // here this doesn't refer to parent but the function itself
                let settings = await guildSettings.findOne({ _id: message.guild.id });
                if (!settings){
                    settings = await guildSettings.create({
                        _id: message.guild.id,
                        prefix: '-',
                    });
                    await settings.save();
                    console.log('entry created')
                }
                this.cache[message.guild.id] = settings.prefix;
                console.log('prefix cached');
                return prefix = this.cache[message.guild.id];
            } else {
                return prefix = this.cache[message.guild.id];
            }
        }
```

Here you are using **function** keyword. That means whenever you access **this** inside this function , it will refer to this function itself rather than than the parent function.

Workaround would be to store the **this** value of parent in another variable first.

```
 async execute(message, args){ 
        const self = this; // this is new , no pun intended
        let prefix = await getPrefix();
        console.log(self.cache);
        message.reply(` your prefix is ${prefix}`);

        async function getPrefix(){
            if (!self.cache[message.guild.id]){
                let settings = await guildSettings.findOne({ _id: message.guild.id });
                if (!settings){
                    settings = await guildSettings.create({
                        _id: message.guild.id,
                        prefix: '-',
                    });
                    await settings.save();
                    console.log('entry created')
                }
                self.cache[message.guild.id] = settings.prefix;
                console.log('prefix cached');
                return prefix = self.cache[message.guild.id];
            } else {
                return prefix = self.cache[message.guild.id];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, its always something as simple as that huh? Thanks a lot!